# Difference between two lists of django models objects

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have two data sources. One is a `psql` table (managed using Django models) and another is a CSV. I have to keep the table in sync with the csv.

So, my current procedure is:

1. Reading all the rows from the table and creating a set of tuples, calling it `old_data`
2. Reading all the rows from the csv and creating another set of tuples, calling it `new data`.

So, `old_data - new_data` gives me all the objects that have been deleted and updated.

Similarly, `new_data - old_data` gives me all the objects that have been inserted and also updated.

So, objects with `primary key` in both the above differences are the ones which will be used for updating.
Rest are deleted and inserted accordingly.

Now, this is not a `Django` way of doing it. (I'm comparing the two sets of tuples, not the model objects itself)

Can this be done by comparing the model objects somehow.

**Update:**

I'm creating hash of the object by overriding the `__hash__` function. That has given me some lead. Again, can this be further improved?